# Why isn't flex-wrap: wrap moving li elements to next line on screen decrease?

Tags: html, css, sass

I am trying to have my unordered list (ul class="main-nav-list") of li's move to the next line as the screen decreases by using flex-wrap: wrap. Currently, when I apply it to the li elements, they will move off the screen and not to the next line. I have tried using flex-wrap: wrap in each layer of my code as well as you can see from the commented out section.

My Html is:

```
    <div class="main-image">
        <header class="header">

            <div class="main-nav">
                <ul class="main-nav-list">
                    <li>Home</li>
                    <li>About&nbsp;Us</li>
                    <li>Our&nbsp;Faith</li>
                    <li>Schedule</li>
                    <li>Patron&nbsp;Saint</li>
                    <li>Parish&nbsp;Hall</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </header>
    </div>
```

My scss is:

```
.main-nav {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    margin-top: 60px;

    &-list{
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex: 1;

        & li {
            display: flex;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
            height: 100%;
            color: var(--color-white-1);
            font-size: 3rem;
            list-style: none;
            padding: 4rem;
            flex: 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine: https://jsfiddle.net/gac5t3dm/